# How to add condition (filter) in Redis

Tags: redis, key

I have a CSV like this:

```
key,fname,lname,email,authorized
1,mike,gote,mike@gmail.com,1
2,joe,doe,joe@gmail.com,0
3,mark,ding,mark@gmail.com,1
```

I can store in redis based on Keys (1,2,3) but need to get only users that are authorized (authorized==1).

How to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fit the csv in this data structure. You can create **hashmap** with key like 
 `user:{email}` 
 for Example: 
You can make the hash keys like-
`user:mike@gmail.com` with keys like `fname mike, lname gote, email mike@gmail.com, authorised 1`

You can use **REDIS COMMAND** for every row in the CSV 
`hmset user:mike@gmail.com fname mike lname gote email mike@gmail.com authorised 1`


Now you can make Set with the key **user:authorisation:0** and **user:authorisation:1** and insert the values in the set using command 

`sadd user:authorisation:1 user:mike@gmail.com`

You have to insert all the hash keys of user:{email} for respective authorisation set.

Now for getting the all the users which have same authorisation level you have to first fetch all the memebers of the set and then take out the value from that pointing of the hash. For example getting the value of all authorised email from the list - you have to run the query

```
smembers user:authorisation:1
```

This will return the hash of the user. For getting the information out of the hash we have to run the command.

```
hgetall user:mike@gmail.com
```

This is the standard approach while dealing with this type of dataset in redis.

Comment: Thanks. It make sense. Not sure why I am getting `(error) ERR unknown command 'smemebers', with args beginning with: 'user:authoriaation:1',`  if insert went ok...

Comment: Sorry there was a typo!!. Now look it.